# Change "PBX in a flash" passwords on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, pbx

I have a EC2 instance running CentOS and PBX on a flash installed.

I can connect to server using SSH. I want to reset PBX passwords, so i run:

```
passwd-master
```

after following steps, i get an error at the end :

```
Your manual password was accepted!
passwd-master - 2.0.4 released on 082612
CentOS release 6.3 (Final) - 64 Bit
**********************************************************************
* Now applying new password to maint/meetme/wwwadmin                 *
**********************************************************************
Applying wwwadmin password
Applying maint password
Applying meetme password
httpd service restarted to apply new passwords!
passwd-master - 2.0.4 released on 082612
CentOS release 6.3 (Final) - 64 Bit - ARI PATCH
**********************************************************************
* Now patching main.conf.php                                         *
**********************************************************************
Now verifying /var/www/html/recordings/includes/main.conf.php exists
ERROR the file /var/www/html/recordings/includes/main.conf.php DOES NOT EXIST
or is zero length. Unable to continue now exiting
```

I noticed i dont have permission to access this folder : "/var/www/html/recordings/includes/"

Then i tried to set password of "maint" only, and i got an error at the end again :

```
passwd-maint
-------------------------------------------
Set password for AMP web GUI and maint GUI
User: maint
-------------------------------------------

New password:
Re-type new password:
Updating password for user maint
htpasswd: unable to update file /usr/local/apache/passwd/wwwpasswd
```

And its because i dont have access to "wwwpasswd"  (not even read permission)

I login using default EC2-user obviously.

My question is, how can i fix this problem and change passwords?

I tried to use : sudo su command
and then run passwd-master , but it doesnt work.
after i use sudo su command, it doesnt know passwd-master and passwd-maint anymore and i get

```
bash: passwd-master: command not found
```

error.

Any advise please?

Comment: Try running this as ec2-user: `sudo passwd-master`. It does appear that it needs to be run as root, but its not set up in the environment path under the root user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tried that, didn't work.says command not found. I also tried to change directory to where passwd-master script exists, but i got same error.

Comment: If its not in the path, then you have to run it like this `./passwd-master` while in the directory where the script exists.

Answer (score 0):

> If its not in the path, then you have to run it like this ./passwd-master while in the directory where the script exists. –  [datasage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790224/datasage)

Thank you [datasage](https://stackoverflow.com/users/790224/datasage). using  " ./ " solved my problem . i didn't know about it.